# How do you make a request to Post/Get Request to NodeJS without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I would like to run a NodeJS function after a button is clicked and I am having a really hard time understanding this. I have tried Ajax requests but it seems I can't run NodeJS functions using Ajax.

This bash script makes a JSON file that I will need to parse and send that data to the client side java script to display it. I am trying to do this without refreshing the page, I also don't really want to use jquery. I have tried Axios but maybe I don't get it.

This is my Ajax request, I cant reach my NodeJs function with this, nor can i load the file because even though that is a direct path. I think this would work if I could run the function.

I have been working on this for like a week I just don't understand these AJAX request I guess. If you can help please do and give a in depth explanation.

```
    function digIt() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById('mapSection').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        } else {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', "./../../middleware/index.js", true);
    console.log("done");
    canYouDigIt(domain);
    xhr.send();

};
```

This is my HTML , this is written in Jade/Pug.

```
 section(id="digToolWrapper")
        form(id="digToolInput")
            ul
                li #[input(id="digTool" name="domain" type="text" placeholder="Can you dig it?")]#[input(id="whois" value="whois" type="button" onclick="digIt(domain)")]
```

This is my middleware/index.js file.

```
    const shell = require('shelljs');


function loggedOut(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.userId) {
        return res.redirect('/profile');
    }
    return next();
}

function checkForbidden(req, res, next) {
    if(! req.session.userId) {
        var err = new Error("You are not authorized to view this page.");
        err.status = 403
        return next(err);
    }
    return next();
}


// Whois Bash Script!!!
function canYouDigIt(domain) {
    shell.env["domain"] = domain;
     shell.exec(digIt.sh)
     console.log("here")
    };


module.exports.canYouDigIt = canYouDigIt;
module.exports.checkForbidden = checkForbidden;
module.exports.loggedOut = loggedOut;
```

This is my script I am trying to run for reference to understand what I am trying to do

```
domain=google.com
aRecord=$(dig -t a +short $domain)

ipWhois=$(whois $aRecord | awk '/NetRange/,0'| cut -d\# -f 1)

server=$(host $aRecord)

mxRecord=$(dig -t mx +short $domain)

nsRecord=$(dig -t ns +short $domain)

txtRecord=$(dig -t txt +short $domain)

ptrRecord=$(dig -x ptr +short $aRecord)

whoisRecord=$(whois $domain | awk '/Domain Status|Registrant Organization|Registry Expiry Date|Registration Expiration Date|Registrar:/')


serverType=$(curl -iA . -s $domain | awk  '/Server:/ {print $2}')

echo -e "{\n

\t \"domain\" :\n\"$domain\",\n
\t \"aRecord\" :\n\"$aRecord\",\n
\t \"ipWhois\" :\n\"$ipWhois\",\n
\t \"server\" :\n\"$server\",\n
\t \"mxRecord\" :\n\"$mxRecord\",\n
\t \"nsRecord\" :\n\"$nsRecord\",\n
\t \"txtRecord\" :\n\"$txtRecord\",\n
\t \"ptrRecord\" :\n\"$ptrRecord\",\n
\t \"whoisRecord\" :\n\"$whoisRecord\",\n

}" > ./whoisJson/whois$domain.json
```

Comment: Your problem is really hard, if possible at all, to understand without any code.

Comment: You need to create a node route, hit that route with your frontend ajax request. Inside of your node route will be your specific node function.

Comment: Kickstart : button click --> Ajax call to the server `$.get('/test')` --> The server receives the call on `app.get('/test')` --> then responds to the browser with `app.get('/test', (req,res) => res.end("Yay, it worked"))`.

Comment: I apologize the reason I was asking so generically is because when I asked specifically , people didn't seem to understand what I was trying to do. The answer I was given actually helped out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code running on the client can't run **functions** running on the server directly.

Ajax is the right approach. You need to make an HTTP request to a URL.

That URL needs to be made available using an Express route. That route can call your function.

Comment: Would I make a post request like : 
router.post('/tools', (req, res, next) => { 
 function example() {}
}
 , but use Ajax to request to that url? Then that url will run my function

Comment: "Would I make a post request" — No. You'd use that code to create a route. You'd then make the request using Ajax.

Comment: Sorry, I meant make the route like that then make a request to that route using Ajax, sorry for my incompetence. This is the thing I have been stuck on for way to long. I will try this out thank you for your help.